# how to get intent content (thumbnail from mediastore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

Tags: android, android-intent, mediastore, extra

I have worked around for a week , and I cannot see why I can't get my thumbnail. I only need it , and not the actual image, and I read that it is convenient to get it through Mediastore.captureimage with no urifile passed to the intent .
My code :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private ImageView image;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
   }

   public void vignette(View vue) {
      Intent intention = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     startActivityForResult(intention, 1);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   if (requestCode == 1) {
     Uri imageUri = null;
     if (data != null) {
    if (data.hasExtra("data")) {
           Bitmap vignette = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
           image.setImageBitmap(vignette);
     }
     }
  }
 }
 }
```

Actually, data is not null, 
but hasExtra("data") gives null.
Though I can see 
Intent { act=inline-data dat=content://media/external/images/media/8767 (has extras) }
... is there a way to get that extra !

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to get bitmap from bitmap

```
 Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        Bitmap vignette = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
```

call this in your onActivityResult function this will give the bitmap

You can always resize the bitmap to your requirement

```
vignette =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(vignette ,100,100, true);

           image.setImageBitmap(vignette);
```

this will create a bitmap of 100*100